# Alias tag ps1 to prompt

Tags: feature-request, tag-synonyms

[ps1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ps1) should be a synonym of [prompt](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prompt). There are only [two](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124407/what-are-the-color-codes-that-i-can-use-in-my-ps1-prompt) [questions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/127799/how-can-i-get-my-ps1-prompt-to-show-time-user-host-directories-and-git-branch) using it currently.

Answer (score 2):

Just retag the two questions. Then [ps1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ps1) will go away.

Not much need for a synonym for something that is barely used.

Edit: looks like someone already has...